# Is that possible with inAPP purchase server model that first I put free application and after that give different modules with subscription?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I am making application in 4 module with different functionality (free,lite,pro,master) and want to handle with inApp server model.In that I want to make user can download free Application but after download free demo there are 3 modules( Lite, Pro, master) with their different functionality.So i want to handle them by inApp subscription model.In it when user select module from one of them he will get subscription for it.So please friends any one tell me how is it possible?

Comment: There's not even close to enough here to make this question answerable. Also, this doesn't seem like a programming question, it seems like a business question.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know that. you can distribute executable code via in app purchase.. means you can't upload a free app on app store and then add more code (modules) via in app purchase..

You have to build a master app first and then disable the some of its module ... then you can enable these modules via some in app purchase...